# typecasting and check is an instance exists in a vector

Tags: c++, object, vector, casting

I have a virtual class Shape. class Rectangle, Triangle, Circle inherit from Shape and have different characteristics (size, number of side...).
I want to store different shape in a structure (let's say a vector).

so my vector would be: `vector<Shape*> myvec;`

I would like to know how it is possible to know if a given instance of a shape is present in the vector (ex: `new Circle(diameter 10);`).

I have heard about dynamic cast but I don't understand at all how to use it?

```
class Shape
{
public:
  Shape(){}
  virtual int Size()=0;
  virtual int Sides()=0;
  virtual bool isequal(const Shape & rhs)=0;
  int size,sides;
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
  Circle(int diameter):size(diameter)
  {
    sides=0;
  }
  bool isequal(const Circle &rhs)
  {
    return size==rhs.size;
  }
  int size,sides;
};

class Rectangle: public Shape
{
  Rectangle(int nbsides,int size1,int size2 ): sides(nbsides),size1(size1),size2(size2){}
   bool isequal(const Rectangle &rhs)
  {
    return (size1==rhs.size1 && rhs.size2==size2);
  }
  int sides,size1,size2;
};
```

Comment: If you're looking for a specific instance you can just compare the pointers. No need for casting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dynamic_cast` is right:

```
Shape* shape = myvec[0];
Circle* circle = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(shape);
if(circle != nullptr)
   ; // it's a Circle! Do something circly.
else
   ; // it's not a Circle. Do something else.
```

But a better answer to the question is that, in a perfect world, you should use polymorphism such that it is rarely if ever necessary to do this.

Based on the additional comments below, I think you might want to use a pure virtual isequal() in Shape, with `dynamic_cast`s inside the various implementations (the inside of a polymorphic comparison function is one of the few places I can use `dynamic_cast` without feeling the need to wash my hands afterwards :) ).

```
// edited out code that isn't directly relevant

class Shape
{
public:
  virtual bool isequal(const Shape& rhs)=0;
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
  // snip

  virtual bool isequal(const Shape &rhs) override
  {
    Circle* rhsAsCircle = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(&rhs);
    if(rhsAsCircle == nullptr)
       return false; // not a Circle; can't be equal
    return size==rhsAsCircle->size;
  }
};
```

Then elsewhere:

```
Circle searchCircle(10);

for(Shape* shape : myvec)
   if(shape->isequal(searchCircle))
      ; // we have a match!
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. Ain't I using polymorphism in this case? How can I avoid using dynamic_cast with polymorphism?

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do. In general, if you have some  operation that needs to be performed differently on different types, you put a virtual function in the base class or interface, a different implementation in each derived type, and then have consumer code call the virtual function without needing to know which concrete type it's dealing with.

Comment: I updated my post: is this what you mean? Your answer is very helpful anyway.

Comment: Is it isEqual you're trying to figure out how to implement? Or to put it directly: once you figure out a Shape is a Circle, what are you going to want to do with it (that you couldn't do if it wasn't a Circle)?

Comment: I want to know if a circle which is equal to the circle I search is present in the vector. For that I need to compare the two Circle (if the shape in the vector is a circle).

Comment: By "equal" do you mean `l == r` is true or `l.isEqual(r)` is true?

Comment: One of them. I wrote the function isEqual to show what I want to do. For example I want to know if Circle(diameter 10) is present in the vector. If it is not present then I insert this Circle in the vector. That's why I need dynamic_cast I guess.